# set cache policy for static assets in htaccess not working

Tags: .htaccess, browser-cache

I have a question about cache policies. I'm attempting to configure the cache policy for static elements using .htaccess.

Despite my efforts, Google PageSpeed indicates that my cache policy is different from what I'm trying to set.

[image]

I'm seeking assistance to identify any mistakes in my configuration, as I believe I've set everything correctly.

Below is my .htaccess configuration.

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Is mod_expires enabled in your server config? If not, then the `<IfModule mod_expires.c>` will of course prevent this from doing anything, but it won't throw any errors either.